# Palindrome program not working for the number starting and ending with 0. How to resolve it?

Tags: java

I was writing a java code for palindrome number and I saw that the code is not working for the numbers starting and ending with 0.

Here's my code.

```
package whileLoop;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class PalindromeNumber
{
 public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
   Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
   System.out.print("Enter the number :- ");
   int n = sc.nextInt(),nc=n,rev=0;
   while(nc!=0)
    {
     rev=rev*10+nc%10;
     nc/=10;
    }
   if(rev==n)
    {
     System.out.print("The number is a palindrome");
    }
   else
    {
     System.out.print("The number is not a palindrome");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If you read the number directly as an `int`, leading zeros will be omitted.

Comment: Basically use `String n = sc.nextLine()` or `next()` instead so you don't lose information.

Answer (score 0):

A palindrome is just a word that is the same as itself reversed. So just use a string builder to reverse the word and compare it to the original word:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a number");
    String word = scan.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Word is a Palindrome: " + checkPalindrome(word));
    scan.close();
}

public static boolean checkPalindrome(String in)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(in.toLowerCase());
    if(sb.toString().equals(sb.reverse().toString()))
        return true;

    return false;
}
```